Issue with DLIB using CUDA, NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX4070
I'm trying to run my python program on a conda env named 'gpu_4070' (ubuntu 22.04) that use cnn_face_detection model from dlib. I followed this tutorial to install dlib from source with Cuda https://gist.github.com/nguyenhoan1988/ed92d58054b985a1b45a521fcf8fa781 and verified that Cuda uses dlib. (Cuda 11.8, Cudnn 8.9)
When I try to run my program I got the error:
dets = self.loader.cnn_face_detector(self.frame, 1)
RuntimeError: Error while calling cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(&num_blocks,&num_threads,K) in file /home/chiara/Desktop/gpu_4070/dlib/dlib/cuda/cuda_utils.h:164. code: 222, reason: the provided PTX was compiled with an unsupported toolchain.
Aborted (core dumped)

I found on web that this problem could be related to compatibility between Cuda and NVidia graphics hardware(NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 4070, sm_89). But after this I found that it needs cuda >=11.8 (satisfied).
Here is my Conda list:
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
asttokens                 2.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h4bc722e_7    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.33.1               heb4867d_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2024.8.30            hbcca054_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2022.12.7                pypi_0    pypi
charset-normalizer        2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
cmake                     3.25.0                   pypi_0    pypi
colorlog                  6.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
colour                    0.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
cuda                      11.8.0                        0    nvidia
cuda-cccl_linux-64        12.6.37                       0    nvidia
cuda-command-line-tools   12.6.1                        0    nvidia
cuda-compiler             12.6.0                        0    nvidia
cuda-cudart               12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-cudart-dev           12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-cudart-dev_linux-64  12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-cudart-static        12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-cudart-static_linux-64 12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-cudart_linux-64      12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-cuobjdump            12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-cupti                12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-cupti-dev            12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-cuxxfilt             12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-demo-suite           12.4.127                      0    nvidia
cuda-documentation        12.4.127                      0    nvidia
cuda-driver-dev           12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-driver-dev_linux-64  12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-gdb                  12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-libraries            12.6.1                        0    nvidia
cuda-libraries-dev        12.6.1                        0    nvidia
cuda-libraries-static     12.6.1                        0    nvidia
cuda-nsight               12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-nvcc                 12.4.131                      0    nvidia
cuda-nvdisasm             12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-nvml-dev             12.6.68                       2    nvidia
cuda-nvprof               12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-nvprune              12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-nvrtc                12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-nvrtc-dev            12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-nvrtc-static         12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-nvtx                 12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-nvvp                 12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-opencl               12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-opencl-dev           12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-profiler-api         12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-runtime              12.6.1                        0    nvidia
cuda-sanitizer-api        12.6.68                       0    nvidia
cuda-toolkit              12.4.1                        0    nvidia
cuda-tools                12.6.1                        0    nvidia
cuda-version              12.6                          3    nvidia
cuda-visual-tools         12.6.1                        0    nvidia
cudnn                     8.9.7.29             h092f7fd_3    conda-forge
cycler                    0.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
cython                    3.0.11                   pypi_0    pypi
dbus                      1.13.18              hb2f20db_0  
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dlib                      19.24.99                 pypi_0    pypi
executing                 2.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.6.3                h5888daf_0    conda-forge
ffmpeg-python             0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
filelock                  3.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
fontconfig                2.14.2               h14ed4e7_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.12.1               h267a509_2    conda-forge
fsspec                    2024.9.0                 pypi_0    pypi
future                    1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
gds-tools                 1.11.1.6                      0    nvidia
glib                      2.80.3               h315aac3_2    conda-forge
glib-tools                2.80.3               h8fdd7da_2    conda-forge
gmp                       6.3.0                hac33072_2    conda-forge
huggingface-hub           0.25.1                   pypi_0    pypi
icu                       75.1                 he02047a_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.4                      pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   8.12.2             pyh41d4057_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.19.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
keyutils                  1.6.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.7                    pypi_0    pypi
krb5                      1.21.3               h659f571_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.43                 h712a8e2_0    conda-forge
libcublas                 12.6.1.4                      0    nvidia
libcublas-dev             12.6.1.4                      0    nvidia
libcublas-static          12.6.1.4                      0    nvidia
libcufft                  11.2.6.59                     0    nvidia
libcufft-dev              11.2.6.59                     0    nvidia
libcufft-static           11.2.6.59                     0    nvidia
libcufile                 1.11.1.6                      0    nvidia
libcufile-dev             1.11.1.6                      0    nvidia
libcufile-static          1.11.1.6                      0    nvidia
libcurand                 10.3.7.68                     0    nvidia
libcurand-dev             10.3.7.68                     0    nvidia
libcurand-static          10.3.7.68                     0    nvidia
libcurl                   8.10.1               hbbe4b11_0    conda-forge
libcusolver               11.6.4.69                     0    nvidia
libcusolver-dev           11.6.4.69                     0    nvidia
libcusolver-static        11.6.4.69                     0    nvidia
libcusparse               12.5.3.3                      0    nvidia
libcusparse-dev           12.5.3.3                      0    nvidia
libcusparse-static        12.5.3.3                      0    nvidia
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 hd590300_2    conda-forge
libexpat                  2.6.3                h5888daf_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libgcc                    14.1.0               h77fa898_1    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 14.1.0               h69a702a_1    conda-forge
libglib                   2.80.3               h315aac3_2    conda-forge
libgomp                   14.1.0               h77fa898_1    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 hd590300_2    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.58.0               h47da74e_1    conda-forge
libnpp                    12.3.1.54                     0    nvidia
libnpp-dev                12.3.1.54                     0    nvidia
libnpp-static             12.3.1.54                     0    nvidia
libnsl                    2.0.1                hd590300_0    conda-forge
libnvfatbin               12.6.68                       0    nvidia
libnvfatbin-dev           12.6.68                       0    nvidia
libnvfatbin-static        12.6.68                       0    nvidia
libnvjitlink              12.6.68                       0    nvidia
libnvjitlink-dev          12.6.68                       0    nvidia
libnvjitlink-static       12.6.68                       0    nvidia
libnvjpeg                 12.3.3.54                     0    nvidia
libnvjpeg-dev             12.3.3.54                     0    nvidia
libnvjpeg-static          12.3.3.54                     0    nvidia
libpng                    1.6.44               hadc24fc_0    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.46.1               hadc24fc_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.11.0               h0841786_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx                 14.1.0               hc0a3c3a_1    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              14.1.0               h4852527_1    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.38.1               h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libuv                     1.48.0               hd590300_0    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.16                 hb9d3cd8_1    conda-forge
libxcrypt                 4.4.36               hd590300_1    conda-forge
libxkbcommon              1.7.0                h2c5496b_1    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.12.7               he7c6b58_4    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.3.1                h4ab18f5_1    conda-forge
lit                       15.0.7                   pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-inline         0.1.7              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mpmath                    1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.5                  he02047a_1    conda-forge
networkx                  3.0                      pypi_0    pypi
nsight-compute            2024.3.1.2                    0    nvidia
nspr                      4.35                 h27087fc_0    conda-forge
nss                       3.104                hd34e28f_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.24.1                   pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python             4.1.2.30                 pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   3.3.2                hb9d3cd8_0    conda-forge
packaging                 24.1               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pcre2                     10.44                hba22ea6_2    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    10.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pip                       24.2               pyh8b19718_1    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.47             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            3.0.47               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               hb9d3cd8_1002    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.18.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.1.4                    pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5                     5.15.6                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-qt5                 5.15.15                  pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-sip                 12.15.0                  pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.8.20          h4a871b0_1_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.9.0.post0              pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    6.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.2                  h8228510_1    conda-forge
requests                  2.28.1                   pypi_0    pypi
rhash                     1.4.4                hd590300_0    conda-forge
scikit-learn              0.24.2                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                74.1.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
stack_data                0.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sympy                     1.12                     pypi_0    pypi
thop                      0.1.1-2209072238          pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             3.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
timm                      0.6.12                   pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.13          noxft_h4845f30_101    conda-forge
torch                     2.0.0+cu118              pypi_0    pypi
torchaudio                2.0.1+cu118              pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.15.1+cu118             pypi_0    pypi
tqdm                      4.66.5                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.14.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
triton                    2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
typing_extensions         4.12.2             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.13                  pypi_0    pypi
vidgear                   0.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.2.13             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.44.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xkeyboard-config          2.42                 h4ab18f5_0    conda-forge
xorg-kbproto              1.0.7             hb9d3cd8_1003    conda-forge
xorg-libx11               1.8.9                hb711507_1    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.11               hb9d3cd8_1    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-xextproto            7.3.0             hb9d3cd8_1004    conda-forge
xorg-xproto               7.0.31            hb9d3cd8_1008    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.6                ha6fb4c9_0    conda-forge


Here my pip list:
asttokens          2.4.1
backcall           0.2.0
certifi            2022.12.7
charset-normalizer 2.1.1
cmake              3.25.0
colorlog           6.8.2
colour             0.1.5
cycler             0.12.1
Cython             3.0.11
decorator          5.1.1
dlib               19.24.99
executing          2.1.0
ffmpeg-python      0.2.0
filelock           3.13.1
fsspec             2024.9.0
future             1.0.0
huggingface-hub    0.25.1
idna               3.4
ipython            8.12.2
jedi               0.19.1
Jinja2             3.1.3
joblib             1.4.2
kiwisolver         1.4.7
lit                15.0.7
MarkupSafe         2.1.5
matplotlib         3.3.4
matplotlib-inline  0.1.7
mpmath             1.3.0
networkx           3.0
numpy              1.24.1
opencv-python      4.1.2.30
packaging          24.1
parso              0.8.4
pexpect            4.9.0
pickleshare        0.7.5
pillow             10.2.0
pip                24.2
prompt_toolkit     3.0.47
ptyprocess         0.7.0
pure_eval          0.2.3
Pygments           2.18.0
pyparsing          3.1.4
PyQt5              5.15.6
PyQt5-Qt5          5.15.15
PyQt5_sip          12.15.0
python-dateutil    2.9.0.post0
PyYAML             6.0.2
requests           2.28.1
scikit-learn       0.24.2
scipy              1.10.1
setuptools         74.1.2
six                1.16.0
stack-data         0.6.2
sympy              1.12
thop               0.1.1.post2209072238
threadpoolctl      3.5.0
timm               0.6.12
torch              2.0.0+cu118
torchaudio         2.0.1+cu118
torchvision        0.15.1+cu118
tqdm               4.66.5
traitlets          5.14.3
triton             2.0.0
typing_extensions  4.12.2
urllib3            1.26.13
vidgear            0.2.4
wcwidth            0.2.13
wheel              0.44.0


What I did:
First I created the conda environment with python 3.8 and cmake, then I installed cuda=11.8 cudnn=8.9 and finally I installed dlib from source (following the cited tutorial). I was expecting that the model works with this Cuda version but it doesn't. The model works perfectly with cpu(but very slow obviously).

Your GPU driver might be to old. What is the output of nvidia-smi?

| NVIDIA-SMI 535.183.01             Driver Version: 535.183.01   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 ...    Off | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   39C    P8               3W /  55W |     17MiB /  8188MiB |      0%      Default |

your nvidia-smi lists cuda version 12.2, while you have 12.6 installed in your env. Try upgrading your nvidia driver

Adding "SOLVED" to the title is not how you mark a question as answered on StackOverflow. Generally you can write an answer to your own question and mark that answer as accepted to mark the question as "solved". In this case I don't think this is a good idea because of the duplicate I linked above.
